# Is there an uppercase @ symbol?

Tags: symbols

Maybe the question is weird, but is there any way to type an "uppercase" @ symbol (which would be like "A", but with the swirl around as in the "@")?

I've been checking different packages / manuals but I can't find anything related...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems much like asking for an uppercase comma. `;-)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get what you pay for.  I bear no personal responsibility if Hermann Zapf is turning over in his grave.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\def\fauxat{\raisebox{-.35ex}{\stackinset{c}{+.05ex}{c}{-.13ex}{\scalebox{.82}{%
    \stackunder[.1pt]{\itshape a}{\textcolor{white}{%
      \kern.7ex\rule{1ex}{.2ex}}}}}{\textsf{\textit{O}}}}}
\def\fauxAt{\raisebox{-.38ex}{\stackinset{c}{+.09ex}{c}{-.07ex}{\scalebox{.73}{%
    \stackunder[.0pt]{\itshape A}{\textcolor{white}{%
      \kern.7ex\rule{1ex}{.2ex}}}}}{\scalebox{1.2}{\textsf{\textit{O}}}}}}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
mailto:name\fauxat domain.tld

mailto:NAME\fauxAt DOMAIN.TLD
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one finds the surrounding "O" too thick for the symbol, one can remove the occurrence of `\textsf` to get the following.  I think it actually looks nicer.

[image]

Comment: Zapf rotating in it is more likely...

Comment: @naphaneal Perhaps we can strap a coil to him and harness a green energy source.

Comment: Thanks, that would do the trick! And don't worry: it is not intended to be used as the "standard" @ symbol, nor in any uppercase mail address of any kind! ;-)

Comment: @Johanovski Well, it does have one redeeming characteristic:  if you copy and paste it from a PDF, you will not produce a valid email address.  Thus, it is email-crawler resistant!

Comment: No "personal responsibility", but who will grant you @bsolution for this typographical sin.

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\AT}{%
\hskip-.55cm\vtop{\hsize 1.2cm{\raisebox{.05em}{\rotatebox{-20}%            
{\Large O }}\hskip-.53cm \textit{A}\textcolor{white}%        
{\vskip-.405cm\bfseries {\ } \_}\textcolor{white}%
{\hskip-.3cm\vskip-.405cm\bfseries {\ } \_}%
\relax}}\hskip-.08in}

\begin{document}

mailto:BOB\AT LARGE

\end{document}
```